# Log all exceptions thrown in PHP

Tags: php, exception

I would like to log the stacktrace of all exceptions thrown caught or uncaught.

Is there a way to do this without having to change every catch method in my application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [set global exception handler](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-exception-handler.php) so you will get all uncaught exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the methods from the phps [base Exception class](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php).
Use getMessage to get the message Oh no! and use getTraceAsString to get a formatted trace.
refer : [Log caught exception with stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245184/log-caught-exception-with-stack-trace)

Comment: But is there a way to do this globally for all exceptions thrown, I didn't want to add getTraceAsString to every one of my try catches

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://github.com/php-test-helpers/php-test-helpers to override base exceptions __construct. Just add the 'logging' logic. There is a reason why this package is called **test-helpers** . I don't recommend using it on production.

Anyway...it is better to rewrite your app :)